# execute system command (bash) using assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

Basically I am trying to execute the command `/bin/ls` using assembly, but unfortunately I am failing:

```
SECTION .data
    buf: db "Hello", 5
SECTION .text
global _start

_start:
    xor eax, eax
    mov edx, eax
    push edx
    mov eax, 0x736c2f2f     ; "sl/"
    push eax
    mov eax, 0x6e69622f     ; "nib/"
    push eax
    mov ebx, esp
    push edx
    mov eax, 0x2f
    push eax
    mov ecx, esp
    mov eax, 11
    xor edx, edx
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

But If I change the `mov eax, 11` to `mov eax, 4` and add `mov edx, 7` after `xor edx, edx`. It do print `/bin/ls`

Can anyone point the mistake I am making?
Compiling the code with `nasm -g -f elf -F dwarf ./shell.asm && ld -m elf_i386 -o shell shell.o` and my arc is `Linux kali 5.2.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.2.9-2kali1 (2019-08-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: The filename argument goes into `ebx` not `ecx`. Use `strace` to see what you are doing.

Comment: @jester, updated my script, is it suppose to be that way now? still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, as pointed by @Jestor (thank you), I needed to store the executing file at `ebx` and all the arguments including the filename in `ecx` and set `edx` to null as below:

```
SECTION .data
buf: db "./", 0
SECTION .text
global _start

_start:
xor eax, eax
xor edx, edx
push eax
push long 0x736c2f2f    ; "sl/"
push long 0x6e69622f    ; "nib/"
mov ebx, esp
push eax
push byte 0x2f
mov esi, esp

push eax
push esi
push ebx
mov ecx, esp
mov eax, 0x0b
int 0x80

mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

after my working shell, the `ecx` looked like below:

```
(gdb) x/50x $ecx
0xffffd370:     0xffffd384      0xffffd37c      0x00000000      0x0000002f
0xffffd380:     0x00000000      0x6e69622f      0x736c2f2f      0x00000000
```